# Mock imported function in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a case:

`test.js`

```
import { today } from "utils/date";
import myFunction from "helpers/myFunction";

it('should work properly', () => {
   jest.mock('utils/date', () => ({
      ...(jest.requireActual('utils/date')),
      today: jest.fn(() => '01-01-2020'),
   }));

   console.log(today()); // still logs current date 14-10-2021, not the mocked date       

   expect(myFunction()).toEqual(today());
});
```

`myFunction.js`

```
import { today } from "utils/date";

export const myFunction = () => today();
```

`today` is a function that returns todays date. But for testing purposes I need that function **to always return the same date**, e.g. `"01-01-2020"`.

#### Note: as you can see that "today" function is used in the test as well as inside the tested (myFunction) function, so it has to return the same mocked value like everywhere in the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`jest.mock()` is invoked in the test case functional scope. Module imports are hoisted (internally moved to the beginning of the current scope). The original `today` function is imported before `jest.mock()` mocks the `utils/date` module.

You can move the `jest.mock()` from test case functional scope to module scope. Jest will automatically hoist `jest.mock` calls to the top of the module (before any imports). So that when you import the `today` function, it is already being mocked.

See [Using with ES module imports](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports):

> If you're using ES module imports then you'll normally be inclined to put your `import` statements at the top of the test file. But often you need to instruct Jest to use a mock before modules use it. For this reason, Jest will automatically hoist `jest.mock` calls to the top of the module (before any imports).

```js
import { today } from 'utils/date';

jest.mock('utils/date', () => ({
  today: jest.fn(() => '01-01-2020'),
}));

it('should work properly', () => {
  expect(jest.isMockFunction(today)).toBeTruthy();
  expect(today()).toBe('01-01-2020');
});
```

Comment: How can i run "toBeCalledWith" and "toBeCalledTimes" on the mocked method?